# how can I fix this code so that I can calculate 2 fraction and return the sum as one floating point number?

Tags: c

```
double fracsum (int a, int b, int c, int d){
    float sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        sum += a;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f\n",
    fracsum(1,2,2,4),
    fracsum(1,4,1,8),
    fracsum(4,3,5,6));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: How `fracsum` should use `b`, `c` and `d`?

Comment: I think this is a covered "Write-Code-for-me" question to calculate the fractions and return their sum in `fracsum()`.

Comment: What output do you expect? You also need to explain what `fracsum` is suppsed to do? It is totally unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you want. But I'd take a wild-elbow guess
that it's **fracsum=(a/b)+(c/d)**. And if that's indeed what you want, then

```
double fracsum (int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  return ( ((double)a)/((double)b) + ((double)c)/((double)d) ); }
```

Couldn't be much easier.

Comment: Make the function take `double` arguments and the compiler will convert the values automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much! and sorry for not being clear enough in my question. that is exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
float fracsum (float a, float b, float c, float d) {
    return (a / b + c / d);
}
```

However the problem was maybe that you cannot divide int variables, you have to use float as argument type..

Comment: You can divide integers, but you don't get fractional results unless you convert the integers into floating point before dividing.